# OpenVPN and multicast routing

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, multicast

I have setup an OpenVPN server for remote clients to access a server that will be sending them multicast traffic, however I am unable to receive any multicast traffic. The application makes a successful connection to the server in question, but traffic is not flowing. Is this possible in a TUN setup? I would like to avoid a bridged setup if possible.

**NETWORK TOPOLOGY**
Internal LAN 172.30.66.0/24

VPN IP 172.30.66.157
Public IP xxx.xxx.xxx.167
VPN TUN IP 10.8.0.1

Router/Firewall/Gateway 172.30.66.1 ( Separate server from the VPN server)
Public IP xxx.xxx.xxx.161

**Server Config**
port 1195
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 172.30.66.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append openvpn.log
verb 4
explicit-exit-notify 1

**Client Config**
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.167 1195
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 4

**ROUTING AND FIREWALL INFO**

**Network and routing info for the gateway/router**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:B8:E0:34
      inet addr:172.30.66.1  Bcast:172.30.66.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:feb8:e034/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:60590989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:124713096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:4959044399 (4.6 GiB)  TX bytes:79112208698 (73.6 GiB)
      Interrupt:28 Memory:da020000-da040000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:B8:E0:35
      inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.62  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.63  Mask:255.255.255.252
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:feb8:e035/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:143591842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:433909800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:87043706669 (81.0 GiB)  TX bytes:166155469966 (154.7 GiB)
      Interrupt:36 Memory:da060000-da080000

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:B8:E0:36
      inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.161  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.175  Mask:255.255.255.240
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:feb8:e036/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:374270778 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2437893 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:158649519904 (147.7 GiB)  TX bytes:552647203 (527.0 MiB)
      Interrupt:36 Memory:da120000-da140000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:688 (688.0 b)  TX bytes:688 (688.0 b)


Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
xxx.xxx.xxx.60  *               255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eth1
xxx.xxx.xxx.160  *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth2
172.30.66.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        172.30.66.157   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         xxx.xxx.xxx.61. 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

**Network and routing info for the VPN server**

```
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:E2:B3:2E
      inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.167  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.175  Mask:255.255.255.240
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8222 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2009 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1235747 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:462680 (451.8 KiB)

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:E2:B3:2F
      inet addr:172.30.66.157  Bcast:172.30.66.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:38220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:9821255 (9.3 MiB)  TX bytes:64314 (62.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
      RX bytes:36072 (35.2 KiB)  TX bytes:228498 (223.1 KiB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
209.117.52.160  *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth2
172.30.66.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
default         Router-Eth0-P 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth3
```

**Current IPTABLES on the VPN**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 34819 packets, 9286K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
5659 1040K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2   115 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       172.30.66.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
2   104 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
4   160 DROP       tcp  --  eth2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth3   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:1195
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 160 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
24  3232 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   eth3    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
21  4265 ACCEPT     all  --  eth3   tun+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2426 packets, 520K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
448  231K ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

**Current IPTABLES on the router/gateway**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1607 packets, 117K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
289  254K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8
10   688 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       172.30.66.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       172.30.66.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:161
221K   13M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10050
101M   59G ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
6732  431K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
285 12124 DROP       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
973 58340 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       172.30.66.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53
17337 1158K ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:68 dpt:67
1200  394K ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:68 dpt:67
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10050
0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:500 dpt:500
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:4500 dpt:4500
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           PKTTYPE = multicast
0     0 ACCEPT     2    --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
235K   57M DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5168  226K DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x02

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 26053 packets, 1581K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       172.20.176.64/28     172.30.66.0/24      policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto 50
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth1    172.30.66.0/24       172.20.176.64/28    policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 2 proto 50
86M   44G ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       172.20.168.64/28     172.30.66.0/24      policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 1 proto 50
39M 1833M ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth1    172.30.66.0/24       172.20.168.64/28    policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 1 proto 50
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       172.20.176.64/28     172.30.66.0/24      policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto 50
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth1    172.30.66.0/24       172.20.176.64/28    policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 2 proto 50
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       172.20.168.64/28     172.30.66.0/24      policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 1 proto 50
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth1    172.30.66.0/24       172.20.168.64/28    policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 1 proto 50
12M 1317M ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
14M   22G ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
149K 9702K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth2    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
173K  246M ACCEPT     all  --  eth2   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth2   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth2    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
313M  128G ACCEPT     all  --  eth2   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2039K  458M ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   eth2    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.30.66.157       udp dpt:1195 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   eth3    10.8.0.0/24          172.30.66.0/24      ctstate NEW
28  1568 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 103K packets, 7158K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
46M 5245M ACCEPT     esp  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
18  2960 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:500 dpt:500
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:4500 dpt:4500
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Multicast routing is very different than unicast routing. Multicast is a form of broadcast, and like broadcast, it will not normally cross a layer-3 device, e.g. router. To overcome this, you use IGMP and PIM to route multicast. You should also be aware that many tunnels cannot transport multicast. You need a GRE tunnel.

Comment: I can change to tap if that would help. I would like to avoid a bridge though. Can I mangle the matching frames with an iptable rule?

Comment: What you need to do is to run IGMP on the LANs where the source and destination(s) are, and PIM on your routers. Multicast will start out with a TTL of `1`, and PIM-DM will send it everywhere, while PIM-SM will  use an RP. Multicast routing is _very_ different than unicast routing. Modern switches with IGMP snooping will also be a problem on the LANs. See [this ahswer](https://serverfault.com/questions/814259/use-ip-route-add-to-add-multicast-routes-to-multiple-interfaces/814296#814296) that I wrote for someone else that explains things.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look more into that. I greatly appreciate it.