# Set up multicast route across a middle hop

Tags: routing, openvpn, multicast

I have a host with two Docker containers (with `NET_ADMIN` capability):

- `backend` with an interface `eth0` (`172.16.7.3`)
- `openvpn-server` with interfaces `eth0` (`172.16.7.2`) and `tun0` (`10.8.0.1`), running an OpenVPN server (tun mode)

There is an OpenVPN client on another machine `openvpn-client` with interface `tun0` (`10.8.0.2`). The VPN is working.

**Additional route setup:**

- `backend` has routes `10.8.0.0/24 via 172.16.7.2` and `224.0.0.0/4 via eth0`.
- `openvpn-server` has routes `10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0` and `224.0.0.0/4 dev tun0`.

`backend` can successfully ping `openvpn-client` (routed through `openvpn-server`): `ping 10.8.0.2` works like a charm.

**Observations:**

When I run `ping -t3 239.1.2.3` on `openvpn-server`, those go through the VPN tunnel, and I can see the ICMP packets arriving on `openvpn-client` (with `tcpdump -i tun0 net 224.0.0.0/4` on `openvpn-client`).

Also, when I run `ping -t3 239.1.2.3` on `backend`, those exit through that host's `eth0` and enter on `openvpn-server`'s `eth0`. I can see them on `openvpn-server` using `tcpdump -i eth0 net 224.0.0.0/4`.

**Problem:**

I would like to be able to run `ping -t3 239.1.2.3` on `backend` and have the pings forwarded to `openvpn-client`, just as if `10.8.0.2` had been pinged. (The final goal is to multicast UDP packets from `backend` to all VPN clients.)

My attempt:

```
smcroute -d -n -j eth0 239.1.2.3 -a eth0 172.16.7.3 239.1.2.3 tun0
```

I thought this would set up the multicast route, but actually it does nothing. I cannot see outgoing ICMP packets on `openvpn-server`'s `tun0`. -- What's wrong?

---

I also tried setting up `pimd` on any two pairs of the three hosts, and also on all three of them. As a result, I could do an `iperf` benchmark (as suggested [here](https://troglobit.com/howto/multicast/)) between `backend` and `openvpn-server`, and also between `openvpn-server` and `openvpn-client`, but not between `backend` and `openvpn-client`. It looks like the forwarding/routing across the hop in the middle somehow does not work. (I had set the TTL to 5, so that should not be the issue.)

I am happy to provide more details if needed (such as `ip route list` output), but did not want to clutter the question unnecessarily.

Comment: See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/814296/324849).

Comment: I know that I need to set up an IGMP daemon on the hosts, and as I said above, I already did that. What else is required? I am not sure how to tell openvpn-client which multicast group to join...

Comment: By the way, multicast addresses in the `225.0.0.0/8` range are RESERVED and not to be use. You probably want to use multicast addressing in the Organization-Local scope of `239.0.0.0/8`. Also, multicast groups in the `224.0.0.0/24` range are Link-Local multicasts that cannot be forwarded to a different network. See the _[IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)_.

Comment: Not all tunneling protocols even support multicast. GRE does, but things like SSH do not.

Comment: In any case, you do not have a multicast routing protocol, like PIM, configured.

Comment: Ok, let's use 239.1.2.3. I have pimd running on all three hosts, with default config. Is that not sufficient? -- I suppose the routing host in the middle needs to know that the destination host would like to join 239.1.2.3. How do I configure that? Maybe that's the missing piece.

Comment: That would be PIM between the two servers of the tunnel, assuming the tunnel even supports multicast, which I have my doubts about. Most tunneling protocols do not support multicast.

Comment: I am not sure I'm following. Would you mind having a chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103616/1000126-set-up-multicast-route-across-a-middle-hop

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I did not make sure that `openvpn-client` joins the multicast group, so the router in the middle (`openvpn-server`) did not know that it was supposed to send multicast traffic there.

The following setup suffices:

- On `backend`, set up the route `224.0.0.0/4 via 172.16.7.2` -- this makes sure that traffic for the multicast IP range is sent off to `openvpn-server` (you may want to specify a narrower range)
- Install and start `pimd` on `openvpn-server`
- **Make sure that `openvpn-client` announces that it wants to join the multicast group.** To that end, an IGMP daemon such as `scmroute` is needed. This works in two steps only:

  1. `smcroute -d` -- start the daemon
  2. `smcroute -j tun0 239.1.2.3` -- to join the group

  Note that it is not possible to run both in one command (`smcroute -d -j tun0 ...`).

This way, everything works as expected.

*Note:* If you start the `pimd` or `smcroute` daemons before OpenVPN has configured `tun0`, things won't work. It is best to start them using OpenVPN's `route-up` hook.

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain. Multicast routing is all about preventing multicast from going where it is not wanted. :) You must specifically say that you want it before it will come to you. I'm glad you got it to work.

Comment: Well yes, I knew that as an abstract fact. My question was how to do that. Thanks for your help though!